# ANDROID - Receive and manage markers in Google Maps

Tags: interview-questions, android, rest, kotlin

Recently, I've received negative feedback of interview's test. They say that they need somebody with higher technical level, the quality of the task was not good enough.

I upload it here, to request your knowledge and teach me how to improve it to improve my development skills around Google Maps and Marker placing.

The prove requirements was:

> Make native call to ****, given a mark
>   (lowerLeftLatLon=38.711046,-9.160096&upperRightLatLon=38.739429,-9.137115)
>   this call returns a list of different resources ( bikes, motorbikes,
>   bus stations, metro stations,...). Once the call has been done, you
>   must draw all the different resources into a GoogleMaps. We do not
>   need anything sofisticate at UX level.
>
> What we want to see?
>
> Architecture
>
> Endpoint call
>
> Show makers at the map with Google Maps lib. Identify different
>   resources according color given by companyZoneId
>
> Show in a new view the marker information
>
> Extra: if user move around map, refresh pois

Here is the paste of my main activity:

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private var disposableCall: Disposable? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }


    /** when map is ready, we can set:
     *  starting bounds
     *  request Pois (MapResources)
     *  set map clicks and infowindow*/
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        val startBounds = LatLngBounds(
            LatLng(38.711046, -9.160096),
            LatLng(38.739429, -9.137115)
        )

        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(startBounds, 17))
        }

        /**EXTRA, unlock to update POIs when user change map bounds, but with requestResource, it can cause stress
         * it can be optimized with feats like:
         * - Don't redraw existing POIS
         * - If zoom out, group nearer POIS into one
         * - Delete POIS out of view
         * */
        /* mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener {
             it as CameraPosition
             requestResources(mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds)
         }*/

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(
            InfoWindowCustom(this)
        )

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "wi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            try {
                startActivity(
                    ResourceDetailActivity.newInstance(this@MapsActivity, it.snippet)
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("MAP", e.localizedMessage)
            }
        }
        requestResources(startBounds)
    }

    /**
     * Async call(RX) to get resources
     * if call is in progress (!disposed) we dispose it before create a new call
     */
    private fun requestResources(bounds: LatLngBounds) {

        disposableCall?.apply {
            if (!this.isDisposed) dispose()
        }

        disposableCall = NetRepo().getMapResources(bounds.northeast, bounds.southwest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(
                onNext = { listOfResults ->
                    addResourcesFromList(listOfResults)
                },
                onError = {
                    Log.e("DisposeCall", "ERROR: ${it.localizedMessage}")
                }
            )
    }

    /** call addMarker function for each item of received list*/
    private fun addResourcesFromList(listOfResults: List<MapResource>) {
        for (item in listOfResults) {
            if (!existInMap(item)) {
                addMarker(item)
            }
        }
    }

    /** returns if item is already present in the markers*/
    private fun existInMap(item: MapResource): Boolean {
        //TODO check if item is present in map, if it's present, it should not be repainted
        // we can manage this with marker hashmap, if it return the marker requested, it exists in the map
        return false
    }

    /** returns one BitmapDescriptor containing the marker icon tinted as param color*/
    private fun getTintedMarker(color: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
        val markerBitmap =
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                resources,
                R.drawable.baseline_place_white_24
            )
        val resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            markerBitmap,
            0,
            0,
            markerBitmap.width - 1,
            markerBitmap.height - 1
        )
        val filter: ColorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)

        val markerPaint = Paint()
        markerPaint.colorFilter = filter

        val canvas = Canvas(resultBitmap)
        canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0f, 0f, markerPaint)
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resultBitmap)
    }

    /** returns one color for each different companyZoneId
     * it passes the value from 3 digits to 6 according:
     * colorValue = abc
     * newColorValue = aabbcc
     * to use it as parseable color
     * */
    private fun colorOfItem(item: MapResource): Int {
        return item.companyZoneId?.let {
            var colorString = "#${item.companyZoneId}"

            colorString =
                colorString.replace(
                    "#([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])".toRegex(),
                    "#$1$1$2$2$3$3"
                )
            Color.parseColor(colorString)
        } ?: run { 0 }
    }

    /** Adds the marker to the map*/
    private fun addMarker(item: MapResource) {

        val coordinates = LatLng(item.lat!!, item.lon!!)

        mMap.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .icon(getTintedMarker(colorOfItem(item)))
                .position(coordinates)
                .infoWindowAnchor(0.5f, -0.1f)
                .snippet(Gson().toJson(item))
        )

    }
}
```

Also the InfoView:

```
class InfoWindowCustom(var context: Context) : InfoWindowAdapter {
    var inflater: LayoutInflater? = null

    override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View? {
        inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val v = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.view_mapinfoview, null)
        val llInfoWindow = v.findViewById(R.id.llInfoWindow) as LinearLayout

        Gson().fromJson<MapResource>(marker.snippet, MapResource::class.java)?.let {
            paintData(context, llInfoWindow, it)
            addOnClickInfo(llInfoWindow)
        }
        return v
    }

    private fun addOnClickInfo(llInfoWindow: LinearLayout) {
        val infoText = TextView(context)
        infoText.text = "Click me for more detail"
        infoText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        infoText.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5)
        llInfoWindow.addView(infoText)
    }

    override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker): View? {
        return null
    }
}
```

And the Map resource object:

```
class MapResource {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: String? = null

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String? = null

    @SerializedName("scheduledArrival")
    @Expose
    var scheduledArrival: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("locationType")
    @Expose
    var locationType: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("companyZoneId")
    @Expose
    var companyZoneId: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("lat", alternate = ["y"])
    @Expose
    var lat: Double? = null

    @SerializedName("lon", alternate = ["x"])
    @Expose
    var lon: Double? = null

    @SerializedName("licencePlate")
    @Expose
    var licencePlate: String? = null

    @SerializedName("range")
    @Expose
    var range: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("batteryLevel")
    @Expose
    var batteryLevel: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("seats")
    @Expose
    var seats: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("model")
    @Expose
    var model: String? = null

    @SerializedName("resourceImageId")
    @Expose
    var resourceImageId: String? = null

    @SerializedName("pricePerMinuteParking")
    @Expose
    var pricePerMinuteParking: Double? = null

    @SerializedName("pricePerMinuteDriving")
    @Expose
    var pricePerMinuteDriving: Double? = null

    @SerializedName("realTimeData")
    @Expose
    var realTimeData: Boolean? = null

    @SerializedName("engineType")
    @Expose
    var engineType: String? = null

    @SerializedName("resourceType")
    @Expose
    var resourceType: String? = null

    @SerializedName("helmets")
    @Expose
    var helmets: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("station")
    @Expose
    var station: Boolean? = null

    @SerializedName("availableResources")
    @Expose
    var availableResources: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("spacesAvailable")
    @Expose
    var spacesAvailable: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("allowDropoff")
    @Expose
    var allowDropoff: Boolean? = null

    @SerializedName("bikesAvailable")
    @Expose
    var bikesAvailable: Int? = null
}
```

You can find full code of the task [here](https://github.com/darkngel82/MapAndMarkers).

Also on ws package, I've added one text with the example response of the demo coordinates.

Any help to improve this would be great, even after losing this job offer.

Comment: As I don't ave much time at this moment, just a quick remark:
break up, break up, break up, break up, break up untill you're forced to stop.
You should seperate view, logic and data code. Therefor take a look at Android architecture components, mvp / mvvm or the mviCore library.
Also look into coroutines, if kotlin is expected.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @tieskedh, can you expand your response a bit more?
After read links you shared, I've seen the architecture used (or the no-architecture) is not the best one... but without a expanded experience in mvvm or mvi, it's not easy to understand.

Comment: Will extend answer later. For now: https://android.jlelse.eu/architecture-components-mvp-mvvm-237eaa831096